# Elementary probability problem involving multiple events

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

> A company minibus has $9$ passenger seats and on a routine run it is estimated that the probability of **any** passenger seat being occupied is $0.58$.  Calculate, correct to **3 decimal places**, the probability that on a routine run there will be:
>
> a) no passengers
>
> b) one passenger
>
> c) at least $2$ passengers

This is how I approached this problem:

$Let\quad O_n=n\space seats\space are\space occupied\\
P(O_n)=0.58^n$

So for question a:

$1-P(O_9)\approx 0.003$

For question b:

$P(O_1)=0.580$

For question c:

${\sum_{i=2}^9 0.58^i} - {\Pi_{n=2}^9 0.58^n}\approx 0.783$

I feel like I've gone in a whole different direction.

If I've done it wrong, can you please post explanations as to where I've gone wrong. I need it for my exam and this is the only section I struggle with.

Thank you :).

Comment: I think your $P(O_n)$ is incorrect.  Do you mean that $O_n$ is the event that *exactly* $n$ seats are occupied?

Comment: Note that if exactly $n$ seats are occupied, then exactly $9-n$ seats are *not* occupied.  (The probability that a seat is not occupied is $1-0.58=0.42$.)  Then count how many ways this is possible.

Comment: @Joel Reyes Noche - Yeah, the $O_n$ is the event in which n seats are occupied. At least that's what I took from the question haha...probability has never gone my way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For exactly $n$ seats to be occupied, you would need exactly $9-n$ seats to be unoccupied.  There are $9\choose n$ ways for this to happen.  Thus, the probability that exactly $n$ seats are occupied is
$$P(O_n)={9\choose n}0.58^n(1-0.58)^{9-n}$$
Can you do the rest?

Comment: Ahhh this makes MUCH more sense. Thank you very much :)

Comment: You're welcome.